# R: Evaluate function for multiple and differently-changing arguments

Tags: r, function, apply, do.call

I have a function with 4 arguments:

```
    my.function <- function(w,x,y,z){
       w + x + y + z
    }
```

I can give this function multiple values for `z`:

```
> my.function(1,1,1,1:5)
[1] 4 5 6 7 8
```

But what if I want to give the function lists of values for `w,x,y` and a vector of values for `z`, such that the function will evaluate each `set` of `wxy.args` with each element of `z`?

```
wxy.args <- list(set1 = list(w = 1.1, x = 2.1, y = 3.1),
                 set2 = list(w = 1.2, x = 2.2, y = 3.3),
                 set3 = list(w = 1.3, x = 2.3, y = 3.3))
z <- 1:5
```

Ideally, I would like to end up with a `n x m` matrix, where `n = set` and `m = z`. For that reason, I wanted to use `outer()`, [but it doesn't seem like that is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719447/outer-equivalent-for-non-vector-lists-in-r).

So, I guess this will involve one of the [apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685866/apply-function-using-multiple-changing-arguments-in-r) or some combination of apply and do.call, but I'm struggling with it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mapply` to iterate over your sets. It iterates over the list elements. I use `do.call` to pass the sublists to `my.function`:

```
mapply(function(...) do.call(my.function, c(list(z = z), ...)), 
   wxy.args)
#     set1 set2 set3
#[1,]  7.3  7.7  7.9
#[2,]  8.3  8.7  8.9
#[3,]  9.3  9.7  9.9
#[4,] 10.3 10.7 10.9
#[5,] 11.3 11.7 11.9
```

Use `t` to transpose the matrix if necessary.

Comment: Great, this is what I was hoping for. Can you tell my why it doesn't work if the list of sets in `wxy.args` is an element of another list?

Comment: If it is an element of another list, simply extract it from that list?

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

```
sapply(z, function(x) lapply(wxy.args, function(y) sum(unlist(y), x)))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
set1 7.3  8.3  9.3  10.3 11.3
set2 7.7  8.7  9.7  10.7 11.7
set3 7.9  8.9  9.9  10.9 11.9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(purrr)

wxy.args %>% map(~c(.x, z = list(z))) %>%
  map(~do.call("my.function", args = .x)) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  matrix(nrow = length(wxy.args), byrow = TRUE)
```

gives:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  7.3  8.3  9.3 10.3 11.3
[2,]  7.7  8.7  9.7 10.7 11.7
[3,]  7.9  8.9  9.9 10.9 11.9
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `outer` define `my.function2`, a version of `my.function` that takes `z` and `wxy` as two separate arguments, and then pass a vectorized version of it to `outer`:

```
my.function2 <- function(z, wxy) do.call(my.function, c(wxy, z))
outer(z, wxy.args, Vectorize(my.function2))
```

giving:

```
     set1 set2 set3
[1,]  7.3  7.7  7.9
[2,]  8.3  8.7  8.9
[3,]  9.3  9.7  9.9
[4,] 10.3 10.7 10.9
[5,] 11.3 11.7 11.9
```

Another equivalent possibility that is simpler but slightly more tedious is to write out the arguments to `my.function` using this version of `my.function2` instead:

```
my.function2 <- function(z, wxy) my.function(wxy[[1]], wxy[[2]], wxy[[3]], z)
```